# JAVA/JAXB Applying multiple namespaces when unmarshalling

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

I have an xml and I am trying to unmarshal.  It fails because it is missing the require namespaces.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<tracks>
  <tracklet><sightings/></tracklet>
<tracks>
```

Needs to become:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<ns3:tracks xmlns:ns3="http://www.mytrack.com/TRACK" xmlns:xmime="http://www.w3.org/2005/05/xmlmime">
  <tracklet><sightings/></tracklet>
</ns3:tracks>
```

This example of NamespaceFilter only does one namespace.  I need one that will append two namespaces.

```
public class NamespaceFilter extends XMLFilterImpl {

    private static final String NAMESPACE = "http://www.example.com/customer";

    @Override
    public void endElement(String uri, String localName, String qName) throws SAXException {
        super.endElement(NAMESPACE, localName, qName);
    }

    @Override
    public void startElement(String uri, String localName, String qName, Attributes atts) throws SAXException {
        super.startElement(NAMESPACE, localName, qName, atts);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The `NamespaceFilter` in your question doesn't "add" the namespace declaration, it adjusts the namespace portion of an elements qualified name.

For your XML you just need to adjust the `NamespaceFilter` so that it only returns the namespace when the `qname` parameter is `tracks`.

```
@Override
public void startElement(String uri, String localName, String qName, Attributes atts) throws SAXException {
    if("tracks".equals(qname) {
        super.startElement(NAMESPACE, localName, qName, atts);
    } else {
        super.startElement(uri, localName, qName, atts);
    }
}
```

Here is the link to my blog post where the `NamespaceFilter` came from:

- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2012/11/applying-namespace-during-jaxb-unmarshal.html